# pytorch can not get the device name

Tags: python, pytorch

```py
torch.cuda._initialized=True
torch.cuda.is_available()

#return True

torch.cuda.set_device(0)
#i have only one gpu card

torch.cuda.current_device()
#return 0

#now comes to the error
torch.cuda.get_device_name(0)
```

> return NameError: name '_get_device_properties' is not defined

sometimes i could get the correct device name，but more often the NameError above was given.

if the error was given，I choose to continue to run dnn on gpu，the anaconda will report 'kernel died'

please tell me how to solve this error，thanks a lot!!

Comment: What if you skip `torch.cuda._initialized=True`? I don't think it's supposed to be touched by end users.

Comment: Try leaving leaving the parameter empty. Torch I'll then automatically get the current device. `torch.cuda.get_device_name()`

Comment: thanks a lot. i have tried your suggestions. But it did not work. if i skip the initialized，it tells RuntimeError: generic type: cannot initialize type "_CudaDeviceProperties": an object with that name is already defined.

Comment: And if i leave the parameters empty，such as cuda.get_device_name()，it reported TypeError: get_device_name() missing 1 requried positional argument: 'device'.     Are there any other methods?  thank you again for help.

Comment: What version of pytorch are you using (`torch.__version__`)? `torch.cuda.get_device_name()` should not require an argument.

Comment: version of torch was 0.4.1，my cuda was NVIDIA 9.0.176，should I update my torch and my cuda?

Comment: possibly. Your gpu may not be compatible with cuda 9. You can check [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CUDA#GPUs_supported) to make sure.